# Two way binding breaks in Ember when using a jquery ui dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, ember.js

Here are my routes:

```
ExtractCreator.Router.map(function () {
    this.route('filter', { path: '/' }, function () {
        this.route('geog_levels');
    });
});
```

Here's my view which creates the jquery ui popup:

```
ExtractCreator.FilterGeogLevelsView = Ember.View.extend({
didInsertElement : function(){
    var controller = this.controller;
    $('#filter-dialog').dialog({
        modal:true,
        stack: false,
        title: "Geogography Levels Filter",
        close: function(e,ui) {
            controller.transitionToRoute('filter');
        },
    }).dialog("moveToTop");
}
});
```

And the template:

```
      {{#each geog_level_group in model}}
            <h3>{{geog_level_group.label}}</h3>
            {{#each geog_level_filter in geog_level_group.geog_level_filters}}
            <div {{bind-attr class="geog_level_filter.disabled?:disabled"}}>
                <label>{{geog_level_filter.label}} - {{geog_level_filter.id}}</label> 
                {{input type="text" value=geog_level_filter.label }}
            </div>
            {{/each}}
        {{/each}}
```

I'm binding the inputs to my model in the template, but whenever I type anything in the input field it doesn't update anywhere else on the page, nor does it show as updated in my (chrome) ember inspector's view of the model.

If I change the value manually from the ember inspector, then it updates inside the popup correctly.

If I take it out of the popup (or just remove the popup code), then everything binds correctly and the label will update when I change the input value.

How do I get correct binding behavior to work from inside the dialog?

Comment: Could you make a minimal JSBin (or the like) reproduction? [This one works](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qazacileta/2/edit), but the code you shared is missing some details, like the details of the models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the reason the binding wasn't occurring is that the jQuery-ui dialog function was appending the "#filter-dialog" element to the the body tag, but on creation of my Ember app I used the "rootElement" option to limit the scope of Ember to another div with id of "extract-creator".

My application creation code:

```
ExtractCreator = Ember.Application.create({
  rootElement: '#extract-creator'
});
```

Using the appendTo option when creating the dialog, I can keep it within the scope of the Ember application:

```
ExtractCreator.FilterGeogLevelsView = Ember.View.extend({
didInsertElement : function(){
    var controller = this.controller;
    $('#filter-dialog').dialog({
        modal:true,
        stack: false,
        title: "Geogography Levels Filter",
        appendTo: "#extract-creator",
        close: function(e,ui) {
            controller.transitionToRoute('filter');
        },
    }).dialog("moveToTop");
}
});
```

An alternative solution would have been to remove the "rootElement" line from the Ember create option hash, making it default to the body tag.

*Special thanks to Buck Doyle for posting a working JSBin in the comments.*

Answer (score 0):

Well i faced once the same kind of strange behaviors and the problem is mayBe due to the didInsertElement with child views. (yes you some how have child views as you use an each and an ember {{input}} which is a view aswell).

One way which may solve your problem is tu run your modal after ember has finished to render everything in the queue. You may achieve this by modifying your code as follow :

```
didInsertElement : function(){
var controller = this.controller;
Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this ,function(){
    $('#filter-dialog').dialog({
    modal:true,
    stack: false,
    title: "Geogography Levels Filter",
    close: function(e,ui) {
        controller.transitionToRoute('filter');
    },}).dialog("moveToTop");
 });
}
```